# How can I develop a package to use an earlier version of Guzzle than my app uses?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, guzzle

I'm developing a new package inside of my existing Laravel 5 app. I plan on using this package inside of this app. I want the package to depend on Guzzle v4.2.3. The app I'll use this package in has a dependency on the AWS SDK, which is pulling Guzzle v6 into my app. How can I make sure the package uses the earlier version of Guzzle? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry -- [you can't use two versions of a single package with composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2167).

This makes sense due to namespace collisions:

```
// Foo v3
namespace Foo;
class Bar {

// Foo v4
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
```

There's no way for composer to do autoloading in this case, as both versions use the same namespace and class.

Comment: You could manually load it and change the core files to switch the namespace out to make it unique. That is a horrible idea and I definitely don't recommend doing it, but that would be possible. You'd lose Composer for that package, though.

Comment: I feel just as dirty for having written it. It's a horrible idea, but it is technically possible. The OP should in no way do it. The real answer is the project has a hard dependency on Guzzle 6 and the rest of the project has to follow suit.

Comment: Yep, agreed wholeheartedly. It'll be worth the effort to upgrade the project to use Guzzle 6 throughout. Maintaining a personal incompatible fork of Guzzle is the way of insanity.